# How to exclude a sign of equality in regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex

I write a parser in Python. For this I use regular expressions. But here it is necessary to eliminate an equal sign.

```
_PIN_PATTERN = '(^[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]*[:]?[a-zA-Z0-9]*)'
_ATTRIBUTE_PATTERN = '(^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[0-9]*(\s)*[=](\s)*[a-z0-9.-]+)'
```

The fact that `_PIN_PATTERN` and `_ATTRIBUTE_PATTERN` in this case, return the same value, for example `('ATTRIBUTE', 'ad = 0.013p')` `('PIN', 'ad = 0.013p')` . But `_PIN_PATTERN` should not return `('PIN', 'ad = 0.013p')`, it should return something like `('PIN', 'VSS:F85')`, that is without an equal sign.

That's part of my code

```
def _is_pin(self, s):
        a = re.match(self._PIN_PATTERN, s)
        e = re.match(r'=', s)
        if a and not e:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
_ATTRIBUTE_PATTERN = r'[\w_]+\s*=\s*[\w\.\-]+' # matches ad = 0.013p
# _ATTRIBUTE_PATTERN = r'[^=]+=[^=]+' # matches string containing '='
_PIN_PATTERN = r'\w+\s*:\s*\w+'  # matches VSS:F85
# _PIN_PATTERN = r'[^=]+' # if you want to match any string which does not contain '=' char
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case is not recognized a pin nch_mac  ,  ie pin without symbols  :

Comment: please see the commented lines.